# string with index number horizontal

Tags: python

I want return a list with the string and index number horizontal. The output is wrong.
Just like:
`1 - Hello, 2 - World`

Now I get a list

```
1
Hello
```

```
def add_index(str_list)

str_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "Assignment2", "Akash", "Kanhai"]

print ("(orginal list is)" + str(str_list))

print ("List index-value are : ")
s = ""
for i in range(len(str_list) - 0):
    s += str(str_list[i]) + " - " + (list_with_indexes[i]) + ", "

print (s)

return list_with_indexes
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, is the output itself wrong or the output format?

Comment: The output format is wrong. I want the output to be 1 - Hello, 2 - World

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Related or at least useful for this problem: [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

First you should know, that you'll not get **1 - Hello, 2 - World, ..** if your str_list contains [1,4,..].
Another point is, that your lists should have the same amonut of entry , otherwise you could receive an indexerror.

To produce your excepted output, you could write:

```
str_list = [1, 4, 5, 6]
list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is"]

print("(orginal list is)" + str(str_list))

print ("List index-value are : ")
for i in range(len(str_list)):
    print (str_list[i], '-', list_with_indexes[I])
```

that would return

```
(orginal list is)[1, 4, 5, 6]
List index-value are : 
1 - Hello
4 - World
5 - This
6 - Is
```

______ EDIT ______

you could also just index over the list elements like

```
list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is"]

print ("List index-value are : ")
for i in range(len(list_with_indexes)):
    print (i, '-', list_with_indexes[I])
```

gives you

```
1 - Hello
2 - World
3 - This
4 - Is
```

as python starts indexing with 0, you could write i+1 to start your output index with 1

```
    print (i+1, '-', list_with_indexes[I])
```

to get

```
0 - Hello
1 - World
2 - This
3 - Is
```

(because you asked for that,) you could also define a function processing that piece of code for you:

```
def listIndexing(list):
    print ("List index-value are : ")
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print (i, '-', list[i])

list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is"]

listIndexing(list = list_with_indexes)
```

Comment: Thanks! So, I want to use the def function for this. Is this also possible? eq Def add_index(num_list)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output in one line then store it in a variable and then print it. Also, `for` loop range should be `range(len(str_list) - 1)`. Consider the following:

```
str_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is"]

print ("(orginal list is)" + str(str_list))

print ("List index-value are : ")
s = ""
for i in range(len(str_list) - 1):
    s += str(str_list[i]) + " - " + (list_with_indexes[i]) + ", "

print (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the strings to print all in the same line:

```
str_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is"]

print "(orginal list is)" + str(str_list)

print ("List index-value are : ")
for i in range(len(str_list)):
    print str_list[i] + " - " + list_with_indexes[i]
```

Also you can make the loop joining both lists with zip:

```
str_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_with_indexes = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is"]

print "(orginal list is)" + str(str_list)

print ("List index-value are : ")
for element in zip(str_list,list_with_indexes):
    print element[0] + " - " + element[1]
```